# Java include multiple libraries, decide at runtime which one to use?

Tags: java, serial-port

I want to change the serial library of my application from [purejavacomm](https://github.com/nyholku/purejavacomm) to [jRxTx](https://github.com/openmuc/jrxtx). This should be relatively easy since they have very similar functionality.

But since my application with purejavacomm is well tested and trusted by my customers and with jRxTx it is not I want to include both libraries in my code.

So when I see a problem with the jRxTx implementation in a customer system I can just delete the jRxTx.jar from the customer PC and it automatically uses purejavacomm again.

I wanted to write a small test programm for this to see if I could just catch the NoClassDefFoundError when the jRxTx.jar is not there and use the purejavacomm instead but that does not seem to work.

```
     try {
            try {
                gnu.io.SerialPort jrxtxSerialPort;

                gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM12");

                jrxtxSerialPort = (gnu.io.SerialPort) portIdentifier.open("Test", 0);
                jrxtxSerialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
                jrxtxSerialPort.setSerialPortParams(19200, 8, 1, SerialPort.PARITY_EVEN);
                jrxtxSerialPort.getOutputStream().write("TEST\n".getBytes());
                System.out.println("\n" + readFromInputStream(jrxtxSerialPort.getInputStream()) + "\n\n");
                jrxtxSerialPort.close();
                jRxTxLibFound = true;
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (gnu.io.NoSuchPortException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (gnu.io.PortInUseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (gnu.io.UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError e) {
            System.out.println("jRxTx not found. Try with purejavacomm");
        }
```

I expected that this code would catch the NoClassDefFoundError but I still get the NoClassDefFoundError:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/io/NoSuchPortException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: You're referring in the source code to several `gnu.io.*` exception classes. If *they* can't be loaded your code can't execute at all. You need to look into `java.util.ServiceLoader` and friends, and at the Factory pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! You are right. When I handle those Exceptions as plain Exceptions it works. So that is the problem. Seems like I have to find a better solution for my problem than that one.

Comment: I now added wrapper classes for both libs and don't have any imports of a serial lib in the main class. This works fine but one thing I probably have to optimize is the exception handling. Thanks again for your help @user207421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by writing wrapper classes for each library, which implement a common interface. This Interface has a static `getInstance()` method, which looks in the classpath for the `jRxTx.jar` file and if it doesn't find it the interface returns the purejavacomm class.

```
String classpathStr = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
if (classpathStr.contains("jrxtx.1.0.1.jar")) {
    return new JRxTxCommPortIdentifier();
} else {
    return new PureJavaCommCommPortIdentifier();
}
```

`JRxTxCommPortIdentifier` and `PureJavaCommCommPortIdentifier` are two of the wrapper classes.

If you know of any more elegant ways to solve this please let me know.